# Thread base class using C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, c++11, abstraction

Since I am new to C++11 I am looking for a proper implemtnation of a thread base class using the C++11 multithreaded features with passing arguments to the class, starting and stoping the thread... .
So something like this one:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21114/Creating-a-C-Thread-Class
but with C++11 to gain OS-independence.

I've googled for it but haven't found anything useful.
Perhaps someone is familiar with a good open-source implementation?

**EDIT**
To explain my question precisely:
I am already aware of `std::thread`, but my intention respectively goal is to use a wrapper-class for `std::thread` to not deal with it heavily. I'm currently using the class-structure below (since 1-year). But I'm stucked respectively bounded to the Windows-APIs which is not what I want.

```
class ThreadBase {
public:
    ThreadBase();
    virtual ~ThreadBase();

    // this is the thread run function, the "concrete" threads implement this method
    virtual int Run() = 0;

    // controlling thread behaviour, Stop(), Resume()  is not that necessary (I implemented it, beacuse the API gives me the opportunity)
    virtual void Start() const;
    virtual void Stop() const;

    // returns a duplicated handle of the thread
    virtual GetDuplicateHdl() const; //does std::thread give me something similar to that?

protected:
        // return the internal thread handle for derived classes only
    virtual GetThreadHdl() const;
    //...block copy constructor and assignment operator

private:
        // the thread function
    void ThreadFunc(void * Param); //for Windows the return value is WINAPI
    //THandleType? ThreadHdl;
    unsigned long ThreadId;
};
```

Comment: How about [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)?

Comment: Not sure what you were searching for.  When I googled "c++11 thread", the first hit was http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, Can't stop it (at least without going through the handle). That's not to say it's a great idea to stop a thread without it finishing.

Comment: You may simplify a thread as a special invocation of a function - in other words, I would not make a 'thread class'. However you might have a mutex protected data structure.

Comment: @chris Well you can't _force_ stop it but you can certainly add mechanisms to handle termination just like you would on any other platform that doesn't support force stopping threads

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, Yep, that's preferable in most cases.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I am already aware of `std::thread` :) I've added some C++-pseudo-code for explaining my question in a better way. My intention is to abstract the calls using `std::thread` to not deal with them, by simply starting a thread with `threadobject.Start(); ...`

Comment: Not a good idea really. You'll either expose all the functionality supported by `std::thread` or hide enough details that not all useful functionality provided by `std::thread` will be available. There are far more benefits to directly using something in the _Standard_ library than forcing developers to deal with yet another thread class that is artificially limited.

Comment: About *for Windows the return value is WINAPI*, the return type is `DWORD`. `WINAPI` is simply the required calling convention of the callback.

Comment: Why when std::thread provides that cross platform library. And underneath the hood almost certainly uses the platform specific threading libraries. With Lambdas converting old functions to std::thread should be trivial.

Comment: If don't want to deal with threads use something like TBB (https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void function()
{
    std::cout << "In Thread\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread x(function);
    // You can not let the object x be destroyed
    // until the thread of execution has finished.
    // So best to join the thread here.
    x.join();
}
```

All the threading support you need can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).